# Is there any native available components in wso2 6.5.0 for file encryption and decryption?

Tags: encryption, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to do file encryption as well as decryption in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 
is there any native available functionality or mediators for this? Please help me to do further.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box support for encrypting/decrypting files in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0.

However, you can write a class mediator and implement the required functionality. Your class should extend the `org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator` class and you can implement the encryption/decryption logic inside the `mediate()` method. Follow [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Class+Mediator) for further information on writing class mediators and using them in mediation flows.